# Linux awk grep from file 1 into file 2

Tags: linux, awk, grep

I have regex in file 1

```
.*8912.*.*.*.*81415444.*
.*8912.*.*.*.*81415444.*
.*8912.*.*.*.*81415444.*
.*8912.*.*.*.*81415444.*
.*8912.*.*.*.*81415444.*
.*8912.*.*.*.*81415444.*
.*8912.*.*.*.*81415444.*
.*8802.*.*.*.*84231655.*
```

There are lot of other files containing records like below:

```
0081347504;03.05.2019 10:51;000010;000000001000126289;8601;Kontaktschreiben;;;;;00000000000901326394;
0081349117;03.05.2019 10:51;000020;000000002000044721;8906;Termin vereinbaren;;;07.05.2019;10:00;14:00;00000000000901332422;
0081349117;03.05.2019 10:51;000030;000000002000044722;8906;Termin vereinbaren;;;07.05.2019;10:00;14:00;00000000000901332423;
0081351563;03.05.2019 10:52;000010;000000001000116607;8906;Termin vereinbaren;;;06.05.2019;13:00;18:00;00000000000901332339;
```

I want to `grep` for each record in file 1 in file 2.

I have already tried `grep -Ff file 1 ./*` but doesnt work.

Comment: Is the file's name literally `file 1` (with a space)?  In that case, you need to write it as `"file 1"` (with quotes) on the command line.  Also, if `file 1` contains regular expressions, you do not want to use `-F` (which turns off regular expression matching).

Comment: Can you be more specific about how it doesn't work? E.g. may you provide a sample of your expected output? For which lines should the matching succeed?

Comment: In your regular expression definition, you needn't repeating `.*` since this already matches "any character, repeated any number (including 0) of times"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no harm on being just a little tidy.

First, I think you are probably confusing [`regexes`](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_04_01.html) with [`Globbing`](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html); and doesn't matter which one is, you don't need to repeat the same line 2 or more times (may be you were trying to show that you have many lines to be interpreted as `regexes`, but you were lazy to make each line unique... but, just to be sure). So, this:

```
.*8912.*.*.*.*81415444.*
.*8912.*.*.*.*81415444.*
.*8912.*.*.*.*81415444.*
.*8912.*.*.*.*81415444.*
.*8912.*.*.*.*81415444.*
.*8912.*.*.*.*81415444.*
.*8912.*.*.*.*81415444.*
.*8802.*.*.*.*84231655.*
```

Could be replaced with this:

```
.*8912.*.*.*.*81415444.*
.*8802.*.*.*.*84231655.*
```

Ok... now what?... Well, `grep` it'll use each line as a `regex` (no `globbing` on `grep`), so, each line in that file, should be a `regex`,... thus, if you are trying to match:

**AT**`8912`**AT**`81415444`**AT**

where **AT** stands for: **ANYTHING**

this:

```
.*8912.*81415444.*
```

will suffice.

Then, use this in your `regex` file:

```
.*8912.*81415444.*
.*8802.*84231655.*
```

BUT, if you are trying to match:

**DOT** **AT**8912**DOT** **AT** **DOT** **AT** **DOT** **AT** **DOT** **AT**81415444**DOT** **AT**

where **AT** stands for: **ANYTHING** and **DOT** stands for **LITERAL DOT**, that `regex` is wrong, cause in `regexes`, a dot is a [`meta-character`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html)... you need to escape each **LITERAL DOT** with a `backslash` > `\`, so, the regex should be:

```
\..*8912\..*\..*\..*\..*81415444\..*
```

Then, use this in your `regex` file:

```
\..*8912\..*\..*\..*\..*81415444\..*
\..*8802\..*\..*\..*\..*84231655\..*
```

or, you could use `egrep` which is the same as `grep --extended-regexp`, to use the power of [Extended Regular Expressions](https://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html), and simplify your regex with [Limiting Repetition](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html), and write exactly the same as above, in a more compact way, like this:

```
\..*8912(\..*){4}81415444\..*
\..*8802(\..*){4}84231655\..*
```

(You can do something similar without Extended Regexes, but you need to use more backslashes, like this: `\..*8912\(\..*\)\{4\}81415444\..*`)

So now, suppose you are in a directory with two directories: one is **regex** (the one with your regex file), and the other one is **sample_files** (the one with the files you want to match against the regexes)...

Then, you can use this command to achieve your goal:

```
grep --colour -f ./regex/YOUR_REGEX_FILENAME ./sample_files/*
```

And you'll get some output, like this one:

```
./sample_files/sample_file2:0088027504;03.05.2019 10:51;000010;000000008423165589;8601;Kontaktschreiben;;;;;00000000000901326394;
./sample_files/sample_file7:0089128117;03.05.2019 10:51;000030;000000002814154447;8906;Termin vereinbaren;;;07.05.2019;10:00;14:00;00000000000901332423;
```

You may say: why two separate directories?
Well, is not really necessary, but, the thing is that if you have your sample files and your regex file in the same directory, and you use a command like this one:

```
grep -f file_1 ./*
```

this `./*` is using globbing, and will match any file in the current directory, your regex file included...

In that case, what you can do is, for example, add some distinctive extension to your regex file, say, `.regex`, and then change your globbing pattern for this one: `./!(*.regex)`... this globbing is excluding files that end in `.regex`... then, your command would be:

```
grep -f file_1.regex ./!(*.regex)
```

And finally, beware: you can't use names with spaces in your shell, without escaping them: you can escape each space with a backslash, or your can surround the full name in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to matsib.dev's excellent answer:

Are you sure about the -F flag? It turns off regexes and makes grep search for fixed strings instead. So `.*` will only hit lines containing a dot followed by an asterisk.

Another thing to check is the contents of your file `1`. If it has dos-like line-endings (i.e. the lines end with CRLF instead of a single LF), then `grep -f 1` will search for strings ending in a CR or ^M. Quickest way to check this: `cat -A 1`.  If you see ^M at the end of every line, there's your problem.